# Project not working properly after publishing. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp

I have published a mini project in VB.NET 2010, I'm currently using windows 7. The problem is after i transfer it to windows xp(sp2) and install it some of the buttons are not working. It is working properly when I install it to my laptop with windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried installing a dev environment on the xp machine and debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing .NET Framework 4 on Windows XP? Also you can try to install older versions like 3.5. After installing your program should work.

[Download .NET Framework 4 from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=17851)

Comment: the program is already running i've already installed .net framework 4. what i'm trying to say is that some of the buttons are not working like the update button it is not functioning, unlike when i install it to windows 7 all the button are working